# Changing Apache directives on GoDaddy shared server

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, server

The site I'm working on is hosted on GoDaddy's shared servers. I need to increase the limit on the Apache directive `LimitRequestBody`. I've tried adding the following to .htaccess:

```
LimitRequestBody 20250000
```

But that doesn't have any effect. I've called GoDaddy support several times, and nobody there seems to know how to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the relevant bit from your .htaccess (the lines surrounding the line above)? I need to see how you are including it.

Comment: @RogerCreasy Thanks, Roger. here is my full .htaccess http://pastebin.com/ymMU64NQ

Comment: Is this your root .htaccess? You need to make sure it affects the folder where your script lives. If this is the root .htaccess, I see nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .htaccess file is affecting the correct directory - the one where the script you want to limit lives. To affect only that directory, put your .htaccess file in the root directory(above your script) and wrap your directive with

```
 <Directory "/var/www/path/to/script">
   LimitRequestBody 20250000
 </Directory>
```

After you change the .htaccess file, you need to run

```
 # service httpd reload
```

I hope this helps.